# Change the Chromium update frequency on Ubuntu to Stable build PPA

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, package-management, packages

So, I have been using Chrome as my primary browser for a while now.

As far as I can remember I had set the PPA to the stable build, but somehow recently, it seems to have changed to the daily build that breaks things often.

How do I change back to the stable PPA build of chrome?

Answer (score 2):

All the repositories/ppas that are considered are either in /etc/apt/sources.list and any files in /etc/apt/sources.list.d. You can remove the daily-build ppa and make sure the stable-build ppa is still there.

Any change in the sources must be followed by executing "sudo apt-get update" in order to take effect...

if you use

```
apt-cache policy <packagename>
```

you can check all the candidates for a particular package.

I believe the stable ppa you are looking for is ppa:chromium-daily/stable (https://launchpad.net/~chromium-daily/+archive/stable)

The link has instructions how to add it to your sources.